# Using Prompts in Microsoft Ribbon Controls WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, ribbon, wpf-4.0, ribboncontrolslibrary

I'm writing a WPF application with uses the Microsoft ribbon from the [System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.ribbon(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace. I'm trying to follow [Microsoft's guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn742393.aspx) as closely as possible, but I noticed a few features they mention which I can't seem to find. One of these features is the "prompt". If you scroll down almost all the way to the bottom of the page I linked to (or just search for the word "prompt") you'll see an illustration and explanation of the feature I'm talking about.

I have quite a few 'RibbonTextBox'es and 'RibbonComboBox'es throughout my ribbon tabs, each one with a label next to it. Needless to say these labels take up a considerable amount of horizontal space. I would like to replace these with prompts, since when the boxes have content in them they are self-explanatory.

Is there any way to add prompts to the ribbon controls? I would especially like a nice clean method (who wouldn't?) but I'd appreciate any old way that get's the job done. Just keep in mind I'll need to implement this in a dozen or two different places.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution. Though it's not an official one from Microsoft, it is remarkably clean and easy to implement. I found [this code](http://pwlodek.blogspot.com/2009/11/watermark-effect-for-wpfs-textbox.html) and used it as a base to make my own attached behaviors for the RibbonComboBox; since RibbonTextBox inherits from the normal TextBox I was able to use the existing behavior (though I did modify it a bit).

In case anyone is interested I uploaded the code files [here](http://www.wikiupload.com/2XP5XGZBLZ2JSDW). This not only works for Ribbon controls but for normal TextBoxes and ComboBoxes as well. And is a good solution if you don't want to have to use a separate control or edit the ControlTemplate of an existing one.